# How to type French accent in URL in Latex

Tags: urls, french

I want to add this URL:

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projet:%C3%89valuation

to my Latex

I tried

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\url(https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projet:%C3%89valuation)

or 

\url(https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projet:Évaluation)
```

But they both not works. It becomes

`https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projet:~AL'valuation`

Comment: Please make a document that reproduces the problem,  usually people use `\url` as defined in the `url` or `hyperref` packages, and they define a different syntax not `\url(...)` so it is impossible to guess what is wrong with your code. None of the packages that you show defines `\url`.

Answer (score 1):

This runs without error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\url|https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projet:%C3%89valuation|

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, in my case, it still appeared as `` https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projet:%C3%89valuation``

Comment: How should I display the URL as ``https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projet:Évaluation``

Comment: it depends what you need, for example `\texttt{https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projet:Évaluation}` works (but is not a link) Your question asked for the `%`-quoted form (which is the only valid form really for URL) so that is what I gave above.